# How to set Seek Bar thumb by code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am trying to set the seekbar thumb using code not XML

I tried

```
Drawable a = null;
a = Drawable.CreateFromStream(Assets.Open("Drawable/Icon"),null);
seekBar.SetThumb (a);
```

also tried:

```
seekBar.SetThumb() //Adding the image path but it said the it requires a drawable but it was giving it a int
```

how can i use set the image with code?

also i  am using Xamarin free version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it with the following code.
Hope it helps

```
public void seek_bar_ProgressChanged(object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.yellobar);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, img);
    seek_bar.ProgressDrawable = d;
}
```